# MySQL Error: IS NULL ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 0,50

Tags: php, mysql

When I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `forums_posts` WHERE pid < IS NULL ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 0,50
```

MySQL version: 5.5.5-10.1.13-MariaDB

I receive this error:

> **Error:** 1S111/1 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'IS NULL ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 0,50' at line 1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: SQL Query is incorrect

Comment: What do you mean by pid is lesser than null?

Comment: what do you want? Say in words

Comment: And what are you trying to do?
Your SQL statement there is saying to select the posts where their ID is less than NULL. Makes no sense, I think what you want is this:
`SELECT * FROM forums_posts WHERE pid IS NULL ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 0,50`

Comment: SELECT * FROM `forums_posts` WHERE pid **<** IS NULL ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 0,50

What does operator (highlighted in bold) means??

Comment: Remove the "<" from the query

Comment: Read this [link](http://databases.about.com/cs/sql/a/aa042803a.htm) for better understanding

Comment: It's a query that runs the forum, don't really understand what they want to do. My action was to request the rebuild the forum posts. https://i.imgsafe.org/3e773793e1.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want get record where pid is not null then Try This :

```
SELECT * FROM `forums_posts` WHERE pid IS NOT NULL ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 0,50
```

If You want get record where pid is null then Try This :

```
SELECT * FROM `forums_posts` WHERE pid IS NULL ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 0,50
```

We can not use < ,> also another this kind of operator with IS NULL.

Answer (score 2):

The condition is IS NULL or IS NOT NULL. Don't exist 'pid< IS NULL'.

```
SELECT * FROM forums_posts WHERE pid IS NULL ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 0,50
```

Answer (score 1):

You use wrong query : `pid < IS NULL` is nothing.

Either it will be

```
 SELECT * FROM `forums_posts` WHERE pid IS NOT NULL ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 0,50 // if you don't want NULL value
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM `forums_posts` WHERE pid IS NULL ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 0,50 // if you want only NULL value
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE id IS NULL ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,50

Answer (score 0):

In

```
SELECT * FROM `forums_posts` WHERE pid < IS NULL ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 0,50
```

It should be `pid < IS NULL`

Because In SQL Every Single NULL is different from the other NULL value.For that purpose, We can not use <, > as we would use for other.